# Querying Airport Lat and long from Airports.JSON react native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, file

Im trying to query from a JSON file I import like this. you can find the File [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwgg/Airports/master/airports.json)

```
import * as airportData from '../../Data/airports.json';
```

I put it into a variable and get the lat from the first object perfectly fine.

```
 let arr = airportData;

 let airportIcao = Object.keys(arr)[0];

 let airportLat = arr[airportIcao]['lat'];
```

I have many objects to get the lat and long from so I tried a for loop

```
  let arr = airportData;
     let airportLat;

     var i;
     for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let airportIcao = Object.keys(arr)[i];
      airportLat = arr[airportIcao]['lat'];

    }
```

I get Undefined for my console.log(airportLat) help would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably in the entire airport dataset each airport should have an associated lat/long, so the only way I see `airportLat` being undefined is if `arr.length` is zero and it's never set to a value. What are you trying to do with the nested lat/long properties? Create a single array of *just* the coordinates?

Comment: Yes I am trying to create a single array and use them to make multiple markers on a map. You might be right about arr.length arr might not be an array. I’ll try putting let objectarr = objects.keys(arr); then objectarr.length and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You've only a single `airportLat` value, so when you loop over the airport data and set the `airportLat` each time then only the last iterated object can set the `airportLat` value. If `airportLat` is still undefined after hitting the for-loop then I suspect the array length is actually 0, i.e. you are processing an empty array.

## Solution

If you are simply trying to create an array of the airport lat/long values then I suggest mapping the array values to objects with `lat` & `lon` properties. If `airportData` is actually an empty object then the resultant array will also still be empty.

```
Object.values(airportData).map(({ lat, lon }) => ({ lat, lon }))
```

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const data = await fetch(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwgg/Airports/master/airports.json"
  ).then((res) => res.json());
  
  const latLongArray = Object.values(data)
    .slice(-10) // <-- grabbing last 10 for brevity
    .map(({ lat, lon }) => ({ lat, lon }));
    
  console.log(latLongArray);
};

getData();
```

Comment: @devashishdesai Sounds sort of like a new question, but generally in the render return you'd map this array to a bunch of marker components. Is this all part of a Map component? Would it be more helpful for you to ask a new question here on Stackoverflow and get possibly more eyes on your new question more quickly? You can (a) me here if you do and I can take a look.

Comment: i posted the question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65996248/how-to-map-multiple-markers-from-lat-long-array-in-react-native