# How to map multiple Markers from lat,long array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-maps

To get the coordinate array, I used the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986649/querying-airport-lat-and-long-from-airports-json-react-native)

it allows me to make an array with {"lat":any "lon":any}

I'm trying to make a loop where I can mark every lat and lon, I tried this

```
{LatLongArray.map((LatLongArray,index) => {

         return (
          <MapView.Marker
            key = {index}
            coordinate = {{ LatLongArray}}
            >

          </MapView.Marker>

         );

       })}
```

But I get the error that the lat and lon value is undefined
I also get the error that each child component should have a unique key.

The loop is inside a MapView component

Help would be appriciated thanks.

here are the Error and stacktrace.

```
[Mon Feb 01 2021 11:38:27.890]  ERROR    Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `coordinate.latitude` is marked as required in `MapMarker`, but its value is `undefined`.
MapMarker@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:127169:36
    in AirportMap (at HomeScreen.js:16)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at SafeAreaView.js:41)
    in ForwardRef(SafeAreaView) (at HomeScreen.js:15)
    in HomeScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.js:26)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at DrawerNavigationRoutes.js:23)
    in homeScreenStack (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:68)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:63)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at DrawerView.tsx:183)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at src/index.native.js:123)
    in ScreenContainer (at DrawerView.tsx:162)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Drawer.tsx:645)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:240)
    in AnimatedComponent(View) (at Drawer.tsx:638)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:240)
    in AnimatedComponent(View) (at Drawer.tsx:628)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Drawer.tsx:619)
    in DrawerView (at DrawerView.tsx:215)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at DrawerView.tsx:213)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.js:26)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at DrawerView.tsx:212)
    in DrawerView (at createDrawerNavigator.tsx:47)
    in DrawerNavigator (at DrawerNavigationRoutes.js:76)
    in DrawerNavigatorRoutes (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.js:31)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:44)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:42)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Comment: I couldn't find this `google-maps-markers` package to check their API, but I think maybe the `coordinate` prop doesn't consume an object with a single `LatLongArray` property. Try just passing the `LatLongArray` object, i.e. `coordinate={LatLongArray}`. This will just pass the `LatLongArray` object which has the `lat`/`lon` properties needed.

Comment: same error failed prop type value is undefined,

Comment: Can you provide a link to the MapView component you are using so we can verify it's API and how markers are used with it? Is it https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps?

Comment: yes it is react-native-maps ill remove the google-maps-markers tag. maybe because it is "lat" instead of "latitude"?

Comment: Right, so it appears the `Marker` components consume a `coordinate` prop, but it should be a `LatLng` object with `latitude` and `longitude` keys. https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md#types Can you add the full error message & stacktrace to your question?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: Hi, sorry, that pastebin link seems to be broken, or at least inaccessible for me currently. Can you instead include it in your question as plain formatted text?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem it was pretty easy

Since the react-native-maps api takes "latitude" and longitude" as keys in the array.

I replaced all the "lat" and "lon" and it plots all the airports.